# View string passed to constructor of thrown exception

Tags: javascript, c++, exception, emscripten

I'm trying to debug a C++ program compiled with Emscripten that throws exceptions, specifically [runtime_error](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/runtime_error/)s that pass a string as the `what_arg`. However, when they throw, I just get a number (pointer value?) output in the Javascript console. The string passed to the constructor would be much more helpful.

For example, the program

```
#include <stdexcept>

int main()
{
  throw std::runtime_error("I want to see this in the console");
  return 0;
}
```

compiled using Emscripten 1.35.0 64bit (on Mac OS X) by the command

```
em++ exception.cc -o exception.html
```

when viewed in the browser, outputs to the console

```
Uncaught 5247024
```

How can I see, at runtime, what the `what_arg` argument was?

Ideally this would be without a try-catch block in the C++ code, so I could use the [DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/1.35.0/src/settings.js#L268) flag. There are ways of converting the memory address of a C-style string to a Javascript string, using [Pointer_stringify](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/preamble.js.html#Pointer_stringify). Maybe there is something similar for the number passed as the exception?

Comment: I can't see the point of transforming C++ to JS for browser execution, but never mind. In any case, you'd catch the exception in C++ like so: `try {...} catch (std::exception ex) { std::cout << ex.what( ); }`.

Comment: @szczurcio Can you clarify why there wouldn't be a point in seeing what the argument was?

Comment: Sorry, please elaborate, what argument? If you're asking about the `const char[]` message you're passing to `std::runtime_error`'s constructor, this is what `what( )` will give you.

Comment: Ah sorry... I mis-read your message (or I maybe you edited it?). I thought it said "I can't see the point of that", and I took "that" to mean wanting to see the `const char[]` message, rather than transforming C++ to JS for browser execution. My reasons for transforming C++ to JS for browser execution is that there is an existing C++ code base that has to run in the browser. Yes, understood about `what`.

Comment: Initially it did say "I can't see the point of that", because I was referring to your deleted comment, which in turn was written as a response to my deleted initial comment ;). Anyway, afaik there's no way to catch an exception derived from `std::exception` and print its `what( )` without a try-catch block. You can read about `std::set_terminate` and `std::set_unexpected`, but those won't let you print the message simply because not every type of exception must have one (in C++ any class can be thrown as an exception, unlike for example Java).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way using [window.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror), which seems to be called when there is an unhandled exception thrown. Using this, I can

- Get the 5th parameter of the onerror handler
- Do nothing if it's not a number
- Pass the number back into the C++ world to a function using, for example, [ccall](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#calling-compiled-c-functions-from-javascript-using-ccall-cwrap)
- The function then does a `reinterpret_cast` on the number to get a pointer to a `runtime_error`
- Call `what` on the `runtime_error` and pass the resulting string to `cerr`

An example C++ program that does this is

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

#include <emscripten.h>

extern "C" void EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE what_to_stderr(intptr_t pointer)
{
  auto error = reinterpret_cast<std::runtime_error *>(pointer);
  std::cerr << error->what() << "\n";
}

int main()
{
  throw std::runtime_error("I want to see this in the console");
  return 0;
}
```

which can be compiled using the command

```
em++ -std=c++11 exception.cc -o exception.js
```

and run inside a simple HTML page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Exception test</title>
    <script>
      var Module = {};
      window.onerror = function(message, url, line, column, e) {
        if (typeof e != 'number') return;
        var pointer = e;
        Module.ccall('what_to_stderr', 'number', ['number'], [pointer]);
      }
    </script>
    <script src="exception.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

It seems to work in Chrome 46, and Firefox 41.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `catch` it and print the `what()` string by hand.

EDIT: This *has* to be done in C++ with a `try`/`catch` block, something like:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("I want to see this in the console");
    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error& error)
    {
        std::cout << error.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you give example code of this? Would this be catching it in the C++, or in Javascript?

Comment: This would be catching it in C++. Then you would need to send the info to JS somehow.